# django-extensions - Get manage.py shell_plus to save history?

Tags: django, ipython, manage.py, django-extensions

I'm using django-extensions `shell_plus` command, but it doesn't save the command history (i.e., <kbd>↑</kbd> does nothing). Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem, and running it with --use-pythonrc fixed it.

```
python manage.py shell_plus --use-pythonrc
```

If that fixes it for you, you can create a shell alias to shorten the command. Something like:

```
alias sp="python manage.py shell_plus --use-pythonrc"
```

After that, you can just type sp from the directory with manage.py in it. Personally, I put the absolute path to manage.py so I can type sp from anywhere.

Put that alias command in you .bash_profile and it will be available every time you login.

Comment: `--use-pythonrc` still doesn't save history in my case: when using UP ARROW, nothing pops out in the shell. What could the possible causes be?:

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `shell_plus` has duplicated code from the Django shell command, but it hasn't been updated to work with IPython >= 0.11. You can see [the changes made in Django](https://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/14910).

Comment: You said "Any ideas how to fix this?". I pointed you to the changes that were made to fix this in almost identical code. I do not see how that can be read as "no".

Answer (score 0):

`--use-pythonrc` didn't work, but installing `ipython` or `bpython` fixed the problem for me.